# Elastic Beanstalk app.config option_settings with dynamic environment variables not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using an `app.config` as seen here:

```json
{
    "option_settings": [
        {
            "namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
            "option_name": "AWS_ENVIRONMENT_NAME",
            "value": "`{ \"Ref\" : \"AWSEBEnvironmentName\" }`"
        },
        {
            "namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
            "option_name": "AWS_ENVIRONMENT_ID",
            "value": "`{ \"Ref\" : \"AWSEBEnvironmentId\" }`"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I deploy the version with my config to an environment, the variables are not substituted in:

[image: AWS environment variables from UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how it shows in the console. But in the instance it should be correctly resolved.

You can ssh into the instance and verify:

```
sudo cat /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/env
```

If it in fact it does not work, you can use the following yaml syntax which works:

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
      option_name: AWS_ENVIRONMENT_NAME
      value: '`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }`'
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
      option_name: AWS_ENVIRONMENT_ID
      value: '`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentId" }`'
```

Note, it will still show as `{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentId" }` in EB config window, but inside the instance it will be correctly resolved.

Comment: Thank you! I was expecting it to change in the UI - doh.